# Is it possible to have centralised configurations for all Node.js microservices?

Tags: node.js, config, microservices

We have set of NodeJS microservices and all of our micro services has individual configurations for different environments like

```
 default.json
 dev.json
 staging.json
 production.json
```

How can I understand these things?

1. Is it feasible to create centralised configuration for all micro services instead of having individual?
2. Which is preferred centralised config or individual config?

I also google it but no info regarding this. I am mainly looking for suggestions on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

## Do not do it

The idea of splitting your application into microservices is to keep it independent. Therefore centralised configuration breaks this idea plus doing so (for example with some kind of proxy microservice) you would have to probably run them on the same machine.

## Is is for local development ?

If it is, simply create [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) containers to allow developers easy setup of development environment. Still this will require multiple configurations for each container/service

## Do not do microservices

Maybe what you want to active is not microservice architecture. Take a look [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). Might be what you wanted instead and services should be easy to port into bounded context.

Also keep in mind that **bounded contexts are not microservices**

Comment: how we should relate bounded context and microservices

Comment: A miroservice can be logical (A collation of multiple technical microservices that behave as a single bounded context) and technical (Single piece of executable). Bounded context can be defined as a single group of related entities inside the domain you are working on (Cart Service, Authentication, Catalog Service, Playlist). Microservices on the other hand can be viewed an architectural pattern or a technical service (Single Executable).

Comment: microservices have a natural barrier between them - enforced modules separation by design, same separation can be achieved with monolith application bounded contexts. The domain and application layers should basically be the same for monolith bounded context/microservices. Difference should be only in interfaces/infrastructure layers.

Comment: I guess the difference also relies on the way the systems are deployed. For example one can develop multiple modules, that consist of implementations of bounded contexts but they are deployed on the same server (modulith). The challenge with microservices is that their bounded contexts are also physically  independently deployed (Each microservices runs as a different process)

Comment: This is a very subjective answer, the op has made a decision to use microservices and the question is how to do centralized config in such architecture in nodejs. So the answer cant just, dont do microservices